# CKeditor: How do i change the inline menu/balloon for links?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

If you have ever used confluence or some of these online documentation software's you will know that when you paste a link into the WYSIWYG editor it gives you inline options for that link - to leave it as a link, to iframe embed it or show it as a tile.

Like this:
[image]

I am wondering in CKEditor if someone pastes a google or youtube link, how do I show a context/inline/balloon menu for that link. Depending on the link is what options you will have for that link - same options bar, just that some options will hide or show.

CKEditor has a menu for links but i cant see how to edit it:
[image]

I read the documentation and found lots of different lingo which made it difficult to understand what this feature is called. Balloon seems to be the word.